# C++ - Proper way to cleanup class on heap with vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this class:

```
class GameData
{
public:
    GameData();
    ~GameData();
    vector<Bullet> bullets;
}
```

In the main program, I create a GameData pointer and allocate memory for it with new.  I know with new, you should have to delete the data as well.  My vector above is not a vector of pointers to Bullets, just Bullets themselves (should they be pointers?)  In the ~GameData() function, what do I need to cleanup bullets?  Should I make sure its empty, and if not clear it?  what is the specific way to 'delete' it properly for good memory management.  If my design is wrong, please let me know the proper way I should be handling this.

Thanks

Comment: @Als Of course.  `vector`, like all containers in the standard library, has value semantics.  Objects in a vector behave as if they were members of the vector, and any time an object ceases to be in the vector, it is correctly destructed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True. But any Standard Library container does not take the ownership of pointer members(raw or smart either) ie. the responsibility to deallocate the dynamic memory rests with the user or inbuilt RAII semantics(in case of smart pointers).That makes sense from perspective of the containers because a container does not have any knowledge of the owneriship of an pointer element.It doesn't even know if allocation was on freestore for that matter.

Comment: @Als That's because "ownership" is an artificial concept, rarely relevant to anything.  The objects in the container aren't "owned" by the container, they are logically part of the container.  The only particularity about containers, with respect to any other class, is that the number of objects which are part of it can change dynamically.  If the objects have pointer type, of course, it is the pointers which are part of the container, not whatever they point to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the ~GameData() function, what do I need to cleanup bullets?

No. It is done by the destructor of the vector which will be called automatically.

-

> I create a GameData pointer and allocate memory for it with new. I know with new, you should have to delete the data as well

You don't have to do that if you use some form of smart pointer, such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. With smart pointers, you don't have to delete it, as it is the responsibility of the smart pointer itself.

Read the section *Smart Pointers* from here:

- [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: thanks for the advise, boost has such things and I've looked into it.  Tho as an obvious novice C++ programmer, I wanted to learn the bare metal stuff before learning the stuff that can make my life easier :)  Thanks tho

Comment: @will: I think it should be the other way round : first learn how to use the stuffs which make programmer life easier, after that you should go learning the details, including manual memory management with `new` and `delete`.

Comment: touche :)  One question, is the vectors making copys of Bullet all over the place?  Should it be a pointer instead?  if its a vector of bullet pointers, do I then need to handle deletion myself?

Comment: Presumably, if he is using dynamic allocation for `GameData`, it is because the object has a lifetime determined by the design.  In which case, smart pointers, at least the usual smart pointers, will do more harm than good.  Of course, we don't know what the actual semantics of the class should be, so it's hard to tell.  From the name, I would expect almost a singleton, but I can't imagine any game where there would be a singleton which contained `Bullet`s.)

Comment: @will It depends on the roll of a `Bullet` in the game.  If it is a simple value, which supports copy, and where it doesn't matter which instance you have, as long as its value is correct, then copying is the way to go.  If it has specific behavior, a defined lifetime, or is such that modifications (if it supports such) must be seen by others, then you need a pointer to it.

Comment: It corresponds to a bullet on screen, so contains x/y coord with x/y velocity, that updates itself onscreen after its fired.  If I made the vector pointers, would I have to do some manual cleaning up in the GameData destructor?

Comment: @will: Yes, if you make it `std::vector<Bullet*>`, then you need to do manual cleanup.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about the `GamaData` members, just make sure you delete your `GamaData` instance, since you create it with `new`.